# Uppercase to Propercase

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++, uppercase, find-replace

I have an xml document I'm editing in notepad++

```
name="TEXT"
name="TEXT2"
```

Can anyone help with a command/find and replace that would convert all everything within the name="" to Propercase

Desired outcome

```
name="Text"
name="Text2"
```

I cannot edit the whole of the xml to propercase

Answer (score 1):

you can match the regex

```
name="([a-zA-Z])(\w*)
```

and replace it with

```
name="\U\1\L\2
```

you can find an example here 
https://regex101.com/r/U6F3Dc/1/

Comment: This sort of works, anyway of it searching the whole "" As it's only changing the first part i.e JOHN SMITH to John Smith, also anyway to include numbers in the regex as well JOHN SMITH2

Comment: you could replace
    name="(\w*\s)*([a-zA-Z])(\w*) with name="\1\U\2\L\3 at subsequent steps

Comment: This seems now to only change he Smith Part of JOHN SMITH to JOHN Smith, so we are nearly there

Comment: Also another issue if the name is 3 letters long like JOHN SMITH CARTER it removes the JOHN and replaces it with SMITH Carter

Answer (score 0):

Mark using Ctrl+Alt+Left mouse click what text you want to proper case

In you case from column 6 to the end of line

Edit -> Convert Case to -> Proper

```
Alt +U
```

Comment: This will only do highlighted text I need a command that will search and only do the name= field, already tried your suggestion thanks anyway

Comment: You can mark using Ctrl+Alt+Left mouse click what text you want to proper case and then click Alt+U

Comment: I'll give it ago but there are hundreds of name= fields in uppercase, I would prefer an automated command if possible

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^name="\K(\w)(\w+)(?:(\s\w)(\w+)(?:(\s\w)(\w+))?)?`
- Replace with: `\U$1\L$2\U$3\L$4\U$5\L$6`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^name="\K       : matches literally name=" then forget it
(\w)(\w+)       : first letter in group 1, rest of word in group 2
(?:             : start non capture group
  (\s\w)(\w+)   : a space and first letter in group 3, rest of word in group 4
  (?:           : start non capture group
    (\s\w)(\w+) : a space and first letter in group 5, rest of word in group 6
  )?            : end non capture group, optional
)?              : end non capture group, optional
```

You may add any number of non capture group to deal with any number of word.

**Replacement:**

```
\U$1\L$2    : uppercase group 1, lower case group 2
\U$3\L$4    : uppercase group 3, lower case group 4
\U$5\L$6    : uppercase group 5, lower case group 6
```

**Original:**

```
name="TEXT"
name="TEXT2"
name="JOHN SMITH"
name="JOHN SMITH2"
name="JOHN SMITH CARTER"
```

**Result for given example:**

```
name="Text"
name="Text2"
name="John Smith"
name="John Smith2"
name="John Smith Carter"
```

Another way that works for any number of word but needs to run 3 replace_all:

**First:**

Add a space in front of the first word:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^name="\K`
- Replace with: `A SPACE`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Second:**

Change all word to Propercase:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\s\w)(\w+)`
- Replace with: `\U$1\L$2`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Third:**

Remove the space in front of the first word:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `"\s`
- Replace with: `"`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>